# Login with Spring Security and jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring

How to login with Spring Security using jdbcTemplate?

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```

^this is my JdbcTemplateBean

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(jdbcTemplate)
```

this code gives me this error:

`dataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)
in JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer cannot be applied to
(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate)`

when I'm using data source its working

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
```

But do I have to use DataSource or maybe there is a way to use JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Create config class, which will have method, which returns datasource.
Fields from your application.properties you can get with @Value annotation or with Environment class.